# nodejs how to get value from a function to a variable

Tags: node.js

I have a function calling the POST function. In that as a reponse I am getting a token. I need that token outside the function. How can I get that. Please help.

When I do a console.log, I am getting undefined.

```
let token; 

function getValue() {
  new Promise(function (resolve) {
    request(
      {
        url: URL,
        form: {
          client_id: "XXXXX",
          client_secret: "YYYY",
          refresh_token: "ZZZZZ",
          grant_type: "refresh_token",
        }, 
        method: "POST", // Specify the method
      },
      function (error, response, body) {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
          resolve(undefined);
        } else {
          body = JSON.parse(body);
          token = body.access_token;
          console.log(token)
          resolve(true);
        }
      }
    );
  });
}

getValue();
console.log(token);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to add return to your getValue function

```
function getValue() {
  return new Promise ...
}
```

outside try to

```
getValue()
  .then((result) => {
    console.log(token);
  })
```

also it`s better to pass token to resolve in promise, instead of "true". after that you can get in "then"

```
getValue()
  .then((token) => {
    console.log(token);
  })
```